# GroupBy 'rxjs/operators' to array with key and array of values in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, grouping

I have a question, I am getting an array as a response from web api

Structure of response is simple:

```
interface CabinInfo {
    id: number;

    projectId: number;
    cabinId: number;
    ipAddress: string;
    port: number;
}
```

So now I need to group it by projectId, so naturally i would use rxjs/operators to get some sort od array that i can iterate in html, so I am using:

```
        this.clientService.GetAllApplications()
            .subscribe(result => {
                const projectsObservable: Observable<CabinInfo> = from(result);
                const projectsList = projectsObservable.pipe(groupBy(cabin => cabin.projectId, cabin => cabin)
                    , mergeMap(group => group.pipe(map(() => ({ projectId: group.key, cabins: group.pipe(toArray())})))));

            }, error => { console.error(error); });
```

But it does not work as I want, I expect something like

```
Array<number|CabinInfo[]>
```

all I am getting something complex like

```
Observable<{projectId: number, Observable<CabinInfo>[]}>
```

is there a way to convert it to simple array??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`so naturally i would use rxjs/operators`

You're living in a strange nature my friend ...

Use the `Array.prototype.reduce` function :

```js
.subscribe(result => {
  this.groupedResults = result.reduce((p, n) => {
    if (!p[n.projectId]) { p[n.projectId] = []; }
    p[n.projectId].push(n);
    return p;
  }, {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using angular you can use async pipe in your html, so you don't need to subscribe your observable but you can let angular handles that logic. Instead, you can operators into your observable.

```
this.$applications = this.clientService.GetAllApplications()
        .pipe(
            groupBy(cabin => cabin.id),
            mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
        );
```

In your html you'll have something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of $applications | async">

</div>
```